# Find a basis for row(A) that consists of rows of A and find a basis for col(A) that consists of columns of A

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is matrix A:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
      1&2&0&2&7\\
      -2&-4&1&-1&-3\\
      1&2&1&2&6\\
      -1&-2&2&1&3\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

What I usually do to find a basis of col(A) and row(A) is to find the RREF of A first, then use the corresponding pivot columns in A as the basis of col(A) and use the non-zero rows in RREF as the basis of row(A). So my way of finding the basis of col(A) ends up with a basis that consists of columns of A. But how to find a basis of row(A) that consists of rows in A?

Comment: The columns of the transpose of $A$ are the rows of $A$, so if you know something for columns, doing it for the rows is the same as doing it on the columns of the transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, transpose the matrix and you can find a basis of rows of $A$ that consist of rows in $A$.

Sometimes, a little observation might helps.

For your matrix, the sum of the second and third row produces the $4$-th row.

Clearly, the first two rows are linearly independent.

If the rank is $2$, then you can pick the first $2$ rows to form the basis.

If the rank is $3$, then you can pick the first $3$ rows.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix row reduces to $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Now the basic principle is that the column relations in the row reduced matrix are the same as those in the original matrix. There are not too many relations here to illustrate this but we see that the second column is twice that of the first, the same for the original. The the first, third, fourth and fifth columns form a basis.

As remarked one could do the same on the transpose to get a row basis, but in this case we note that the rank is $4$, and thus all the rows are a basis.